# How are frequency combs obeying the energy conservation?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, laser, photonics, laser-cavity

The operational principle of frequency combs is that you generate very short pulses (in time domain), and that in the frequency domain (due to Fourier's transform) the spectrum of such pulses is a comb.

But this is just maths. And how it works from the physics perspective? Let's say I have a monochromatic continuous laser pointer that outputs only **ONE wavelength.** In front of the pointer I place a shutter that chops the beam into short pulses.

How can those pulses have multiple optical frequencies (with **many different wavelengths**)?

Or is my idea too simplistic and I'm forgetting something?

Comment: You're letting the light interact with an object.  That object might be a gain material, or it might be an absorptive material (or reflective), and so the energy in the em-wave can change due to this interaction.

Comment: why is energy conservation being lost? Before the chopper you had for example 1 W and after chopping maybe 5 mW. No new energy was created, you actually took away energy. Regarding the frequencies there has to be a broadening: What is the frequency of a pulse? It has a beginning and end, surely it cannot be a single frequency...I ask you the opposite: you have a comb, you use your special chopper to get a single pulse: why is the spectrum between what were before the comb teeth now continuous?

Comment: Ahh so I understand that the power of CW would be much stronger than that of those single pulses, and even though they have different wavelengths, it is compensated by the changes of intensity, right? But then again, why photons change their wavelengths just because they encountered a chopper?